# How can I partition the root mount point?

Tags: partitioning

I switched to Linux(Ubuntu) first time two days ago. Now I'm trying to partition the disk for virtual machine use, but I'd allocated all space to root at installation. Is it bad practice? and how may it be fixed?

Here are screen shots in Gparted
1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDVqi.png
2:              https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIHEs.png

Comment: How to use manual partitioning during installation? https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes

Comment: You can't modify a live system. Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and do it from there. Why are you needing/wanting to change the current partitioning? Which virtual machine... VirtualBox? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: It's unclear why you wish to create additional *real* partitions. Those are usually unnecessary for a beginner VM.

Comment: thx, just realize VM does not require real partition. noobie's here :p

Answer (score 2):

> Now I'm trying to partition the disk for virtual machine use, but I'd allocated all space to root at installation. Is it bad practice?

No, the approach to have a single partition for your system spanning the entire system is appropriate: that is how the installer would do it by default.

Think again why you would want additional partitions on your system. Having Virtual machines does not sound like a good motivation. Virtual machines live in a file stored in the file system of the host system. The space available in your partition will allow you to set up quite a lot of different virtual machines.

If you insist on creating additional partitions, you will need to reduce the size of your root partition. That can only work if the partition is not used, i.e., if the installed system on it is not running. You can do this using Gparted running in a live environment started from the Ubuntu installation DVD or USB.